# Running QChainage from python script in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.18, qchainage

I'm fairly experienced in both python and QGIS but not so much together.

I have a series of vector lines I need to run the very useful QChainage plug-in on to get points every 1000m. I have about 200 of these .shp files and have already written a rough script to reproject and dissolve them using the processing module, but I am not sure how to do that in the script. I am guessing the code would look something like this:

```
Qchainage.run(input='input.shp', distance=1000, output='output.shp')
```

But obviously that doesn't seem to be working. I cna't find any documentation on running qchainage from python either.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the important parts are:

```
from qchainage import chainagetool
```

to import the necessary function, and:

```
    chainagetool.points_along_line(layerout='Output_name',
              startpoint=,
              endpoint=,
              distance=,
              label=,
              layer=layer,
              selected_only=False,
              force=False,
              fo_fila=False,
              divide=0,
              decimal=2)
```